# meteor: split code into its own file

Tags: javascript, meteor

I started with a meteor project and I noticed that code is growing rapidly. 
The stuff that goes inside

```
if (Meteor.isClient) { .... }
```

is getting big now. Its all `Template.box....`, `Template.bar....`, etc code, so I think it could be placed into its own file. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they should be placed in their own files and you should put your `isClient` code under the `client` directory and your `isServer` code under the `server` directory. The [examples](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples) each use a single `.js` file because it makes it easy to read when you are only dealing with a few lines of code. However, that isn't how you should build a large project.

Typically your client code would be broken out by view or url path into files where each is responsible for a single template or a collection of a few related templates. For more ideas see the [unofficial-meteor-faq](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files).